# How to use AVERAGEIFS within ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying to use `AVERAGEIFS` inside `ARRAYFORMULA`. Looking at other questions, I have come to the conclusion that it is not possible without using `QUERY` function.

My intention is to average the values of a column whenever they share the same ID.

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56809701/how-to-use-averageifs-or-sumifs-in-an-arrayformula) comes pretty close to what I need, but I haven't been able to replicate and adapt its solution on my own sheet.

[In this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hBdI_M0ddMyIzjb4sd86rPavi_2C0ir4QZjacx2KfHI/edit?usp=sharing) I show the result I expect (I got it by dragging the formula). I've also reviewed the [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage), unsuccessfully.

Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Comment: aprox. how much rows of data you have??

Comment: More than 50.000...

Comment: In your sheet it works out the average for the current ID only from the current row onwards (so 2019_1_JOHN changes from 16.7 to 22.5 to 25) - can you confirm this is what you are looking for plz?

Comment: Tom is right, that was a mistake creating dummy data and it's fixed now. I'm sorry...

Comment: So to best of my knowledge you can't do it with averageif, but can do it with sumif/countif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the formula should be

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(sumif(A2:A,A2:A,B2:B)/countif(A2:A,A2:A)))
```

[image: this]

Note that if there were any text values in the points column, this would still return a result (because count would be greater than zero) - you could instead use

```
=ArrayFormula(if(isnumber(B2:B),(sumif(A2:A,A2:A,B2:B)/countif(A2:A,A2:A)),""))
```

If you had a mixture of rows with text and rows with numbers for any ID, this would return a smaller result than the avg or average formula. This is a limitation of this method. You can't put an extra condition in (that column B has to contain a number) because you would need countifs and countifs isn't array-friendly. It still seems strange that AFAIK countif and sumif are the only functions out of this family that are array-friendly while countifs, sumifs, averageif etc. are not.

Answer (score 2):

you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A; QUERY(A2:B; "select A,avg(B) group by A"); 2; )))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you so much! Both your answer and Tom's are working perfectly for me. I gave you upvotes, but it seems I don't have reputation enough to be displayed. Anyway, thank you again for your time.